# Snapd not found

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, apt, packages, source.list

I'm using a Pi 3 on Raspbian Buster, and I'm trying to install Snap so I can use a Snap app. I tried upgrading all the packages and `sudo apt update` but `sudo apt install snapd` says "Package snapd not found". The repo in raspi.list is `http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease`, maybe there's a different repo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: changing raspi.list wasn't the right solution. The problem in my case was that the main Raspbian repo somehow got deleted from sources.list. Here's what was supposed to be in sources.list:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: `snapd` is in `http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/` (i.e.the repo pointed to by `/etc/apt/sources.list`) ... how does changing the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` relate - all you've done is broken stuff

Comment: Right, but the sources.list entry got deleted somehow, so I assumed I needed to change raspi.list. I went to a fresh Buster install and used the same sources.list entry in the existing install which fixed the problem.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.